# R Calculate change using time and not lag

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate change from one quarter to the next. It's a little complex as I'm grouping variables and I'd like to not use lag if possible.  I'm having some difficultly finding a solution. Does anyone have a suggestion?
This is where I am now.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

x <- mutate(x,QTR.YR = quarter(x$Month.of.Day.Timestamp, with_year = TRUE))

New.DF <- x %>% group_by(location_country, Device.Type,QTR.YR) %>% #Select grouping columns to summarise
  summarise(Sum.Basket = sum(Baskets.Created), Sum.Visits = sum(Visits),
            Sum.Checkout.Starts = sum(Checkout.Starts), Sum.Converted.Visit = sum(Converted.Visits),
            Sum.Store.Find = sum(store_find), Sum.Time.on.Page = sum(time_on_pages), 
            Sum.Time.on.Product.Page = sum(time_on_product_pages), 
            Visit.Change = sum(Visits)/sum((lag(Visits)),4)-1)

View(New.DF)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.  See [mcve] for more info on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Please provide some sample data and your desire results.